Different Servers deliver different MIME type from .NET 4.7.1 API endpoint
I have a .NET 4.7.1 back end where I'm calling an API endpoint and expecting a text/html response.  On one server I get the expected text/html, but on a different server (both running same version of WinServer and IIS, and the same code) the url returns XML.
The endpoint is defined like this
<Route("news/GetVarsDue/{lastMonthAct}/{acctType}")>
<HttpGet>
Public Function GetVarsDue(lastMonthAct As String, acctType As string) As HttpResponseMessage
    Dim response = New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    response.Content = New StringContent("<label>helloBrad</label>", Encoding.UTF8, "text/html")
    Return response
End Function

When I hit the API in Chrome or Edge, the good server returns this

while the bad server returns this

Both servers have the same relevant mime types


Auth for both servers is the same, and both are on the same AD Domain.

I see this error in the tooltip but I don't know what it means.

What could cause a server to return the wrong MIME type when I explicitly set it in the API?

Are the IIS servers both AD Domain members? The first trace shows Negotiate authentication whereas the second cookie-based auth. Windows based auth. is not supported for http/2, the first GET might have fallen back to http1.1  and gave the intended result, and the second GET (probably not a domain member) chose a different auth type and continued to run http/2 and gave a different result. Might disabling http/2 in the IIS site bindings change the result? I assume both servers use https.

They are both on the same AD Domain, and only Windows Authentication is enabled on both server.  On the first I see the www-authenticate set to Negotiate,but how do you know the second is cookie based?  I don't see that.

The security angle may be the reason.  I pasted in an error I didn't notice before complaining about SSL, but i don't know what it means.  Neither site is SSL and they are both running the same DLLs.

I think in the second server, Kerberos Auth. some how does not succeed for the browser (which should also be on a domain member), and it can not get a Kerberos ticket from the DC for the  IIS server www service and therefore somehow cookies exist in the trace. For both cases ; klist command on the browser after GET verb, Security event logs on both IIS servers and Security event logs on Domain Controllers should be checked. Also IIS failed request tracing might reveal the  reason and the module that deviates the http request.

Is there a difference in the global configuration of the two servers(ApplicationHost.Config) and the configuration of the site(Web.Config) that is having the problem?

The good server had .net framework 4.8 installed while the naughty server had only 4.7.1.  All projects in the solution are 4.7.1.  I don't know why 4.8 fixed it, but it is working now.
